# Only in debug session, parsing mongodb connection string fails on unwrap (rust)

Tags: mongodb, rust

```
let mut client_options = ClientOptions::parse(
    env::var("MONGODB_CONNECTION_STRING").unwrap_or("".to_string())
)
.await
.unwrap();
```

This code runs fine without debugging. When in debug session it will show:

```
thread 'tokio-runtime-worker' panicked at 'called `Result::unwrap()` on an `Err` value: Error { kind: InvalidArgument { message: "connection string contains no scheme" }, labels: {} }', src/main.rs:73:6
note: run with `RUST_BACKTRACE=1` environment variable to display a backtrace
```

My connection string is in .cargo/config.toml as:

```
[env]
MONGODB_CONNECTION_STRING="mongodb+srv://xxxxxxx:<password>@xxxxxx.xxxxxxx.mongodb.net/sample_restaurants?retryWrites=true&w=majority"
```

What's wrong here?

Comment: What debuuger are you using? Maybe it does not forward the environment variables.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman It's CodeLLDB on VS Code.

Comment: ah it's saying "://" cannot be found. https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-rust-driver/blob/main/src/client/options/mod.rs#L1214

I'll try url encode.

Answer (score 0):

hmm it's not related.

Summary:
debug session fail to parse mongo connection string at unwrap

- env variable in /project/.cargo/config.toml

debug session OK to parse mongo connection string if setting as:

- OS env variable
- "env" in launch.json

If no advice arrive I will go to CodeLLDB :)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).